# Problem submitting a form using onclick

Tags: forms, onclick

I'm having a problem submitting my form, my code is as follows:

```
<form method="get" action="<?=bloginfo('template_url');?>/contact.php" id="quickContactForm" onsubmit="return sendDetails();">                  
                    <h2>Request a callback:</h2>
                    <ul style="margin:10px">
                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" style="margin-left:12px; height:20px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                        </li>

                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" style="margin-left:14px; height:20px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                        </li>

                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
                            <label>Mobile:</label>
                            <input name="mobile" id="mobile" type="text" style="margin-left:8px; height:20px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                        </li>

                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
                            <label>Note:</label>
                            <input name="interest" id="interest" type="textarea" style="margin-left:20px; height:100px">
                        </li>

                        <li style="list-style-type:none;">
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="document['quickContactForm'].submit()" class="">
                                <img src="<?=bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/btn_send.jpg" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </form>
```

The above code gives me an error: document.quickContactForm is undefined I've also tried changing the  tag to:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="$('#quickContactForm').submit()" class="">
    <img src="<?=bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/btn_send.jpg" />
</a>
```

but this gives me an error aswell: $ is not defined

What am I doing wrong ?

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: $ is used by libraries such as jQuery, but it is not part of JavaScript. Are you including a <script/> tag targeting a jQuery file?

Comment: Brettz, thanks for that. I didn't realise that was the problem. I'm relatively new to JS and JQuery. As soon as I installed the jquery.js it worked fine.

Comment: Brettz, if you put this as an answer I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is used by libraries such as jQuery, but it is not part of JavaScript. Are you including a  tag targeting a jQuery file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.getElementById("quickContactForm").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an ID unless you reference it on the forms object: `document.forms.quickContactForm`. (Or if you use `document.getElementById('quickContactForm')`)